# fork() returns 0, but the child process getpid()!=0. Why?

Tags: c, process, fork, wait, pid

This is the C code to test fork() system call:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    printf("I am: %d\n", (int)getpid());

    pid_t pid = fork();

    printf("fork returned: %d\n", (int)pid);

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failed");  
    }

    if (pid==0)
    {
        printf("I am the child with pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
        sleep(5);
        printf("Child exiting...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("I am the parent with pid %d, waiting for the child\n", (int)getpid());
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Parent ending. \n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output in terminal is:

```
I am: 25110
fork returned: 25111
I am the parent with pid 25110, waiting for the child
fork returned: 0
I am the child with pid 25111
Child exiting...
Parent ending.
```

Question: When **fork returned: 0**, it is in the child process. But the child process shows **I am the child with pid 25111**. I thought the child process pid should be 0, why it changes to 25111?

Same thing with the parent process, **fork returned 25111**, but getpid() returns 25110 (I am the parent with pid 25110, waiting for the child)

Comment: You need to read a lot more. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; we can't explain here what needs an entire book to be explained. Notice that `fork` is *tricky* to understand, so take time! Read also many times [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) wikipage

Comment: BTW, the ONLY PID which is 0 is `init`

Comment: `init` is pid 1. There is literally (this is a POSIX requirement) no such thing as pid 0 since 0 has special meaning to various interfaces that take or return pids -- in particular, `fork`.

Comment: @R.. That's what I thought, too, although on the first machine where I tried it (an old SunOS machine), `ps` shows a pid 0 called "swapper".  (But, yes, init is pid 1.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: It's something of a pseudo-process in the kernel's management of processes, but you can't interact with it using any functions that take pid arguments because it's not a valid pid number. Linux similarly has a "pid 0" that's the idle task (for cpu0 anyway), I think.

Comment: My bad, indeed 'init' is 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the child process shows I am the child with pid 25111. I thought the child process pid should be 0

No.  In the parent `fork()` returns the pid of the child.  In the child, `fork` returns 0 -- which is *not* the pid of anything, it's just a marker.  The child pid is 25111, as `getpid` told you.

> with the parent process, fork returned 25111, but getpid() returns 25110

Right.  The parent pid was always 25110, as `getpid` told you.  And `fork()` returned the pid of the new child.

The fact that `fork` returned the same value in the parent as `getpid` returned in the child proves that this is all working properly.

It sounds like you think `fork()` always returns the pid of the process that you're in.  But that wouldn't make sense -- we already have the `getpid` call for that.

If you're the parent, `fork()` returns the pid of the *other* process, the child.  And if you're the child, `fork()` doesn't return a pid at all.  (If you're the child and you want to know the pid of your parent, that's a good, frequent, and separate question.  Answer: call `getppid()`.)

We can summarize all this as follows:

```
                 parent   child
                 ------   -----
pid:              25110   25111
fork returns:     25111       0
getpid returns:   25110   25111
getppid returns:  ?????   25110
```

The way to remember this is to think about the code that's going to be calling `fork()`: what it's going to do, what it needs to know.  The parent needs to know that it is the parent.  The child needs to know that it is the child.  The parent very often needs to know the pid of the child (and would have no other way of obtaining it).

If `fork` always returned a pid, then after the `fork` call, looking at its return value, you would have no way of knowing whether you were the parent or the child -- but this is typically the first and most important thing you need to know.

(In all of this I've ignored the third possibility, namely that `fork` fails, and returns -1 in the parent, and doesn't return anything in the child, because there isn't one.)

See also [Why fork() return 0 in the child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718225/why-fork-return-0-in-the-child-process?rq=1) .

Answer (score 3):

`fork` returning 0 does not mean your pid is 0. It's simply the return value `fork` uses to tell you that you're the child process. In fact `fork` *never* returns your pid; it returns either:

- the pid of your child,
- 0, meaning you are the child, or
- -1, indicating an error occurred (and no child process was created)

Comment: Again **fork never returns the process's own pid**. It either (1) tells the parent the pid of its child, or (2) uses special values that are not the pid of anything to let you identify that an error occurred or that it's returning in the newly-created child.